# How to use inline CSS to specific element in smarty template engine?

Tags: css, if-statement, styles, smarty, conditional-statements

I want to apply some condition and upon falsity of that condition I want to apply CSS style to the element but I'm not able to do. Can you help me in applying the desired style to the html  element? Thanks in advance.
My code is as follows:

```
<form id="manage_reply_enquiry" name="manage_reply_enquiry" method="post" action="{$control_url}modules/enquiries/reply_to_enquiry.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"
      {if $error_msg!=""} {style="display:none;"} {else} {"display"} {/if}>
```

In short I want to hide and display the form depending on condition.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason to hide the form with CSS?

```
{if $error_msg != ""}
    <div>Error Message</div>        
{else}
    <form>...</form>
{/if}
```

OR

```
<form style="display:{if $error_msg != ""} none {else} block {/if}">...</form>
```